# run random javascripts in HTML Body

Tags: javascript, html

I have two scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://goldenads.ir/showb.php?text=0&uid=230&c=2&mod=h&type=h' ></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bermodashop.com/adcode/run/banner/h/horizontal/1/0/0/null//ref:2066"></script>
```

I want to put them in a `<div>` and randomly run them while refreshing the HTML document. How can I do this?

Comment: i had a random script that could randomly show a text and it didn't work with script! i don't know even is it possible to do so?

Comment: Guys, coach before down-voating.  This poor bloke is new and clearly English is not his first language.  SO is not about criticism, its about helping others to become strong devs.  @Amin--Are you looking to load one of the two `script` tags randomly on each page load?  We need more detail and code samples to help you.

Comment: thanks Matthew, you're right English is not my first language, sorry for bad english guys. yeah, i want to load one of theme on each load page

Comment: You people complaining about the phrasing of the question can easily make edits to it. It's not a hard question to understand. There, I cleaned it up. Happy?

Comment: thanks  j08691 , i think that wasn't hard to understand ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
document.write(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
    ?'<table border="0" align="center"><tr><td width="468px"><a href="http://www.goldenads.ir/red.php?uid=230&pid=97&bid=26" target="_blank" ><img border="none" src="http://www.goldenads.ir/uploads/bnr/1319812021.gif" width="468" height="60" /></a></td><td width="468px"><a href="http://www.goldenads.ir/red.php?uid=230&pid=105&bid=49" target="_blank" ><img border="none" src="http://www.goldenads.ir/uploads/bnr/1319819372.gif" width="468" height="60" /></a></td></tr>   <tr><td style="font: 11px tahoma;" colspan="2"><center><a href="" target="_blank" ></a></center></td></tr></table>'
    :'<div align="center" dir="rtl"><a href="http://bermodashop.com/ad/click/1/90/ref:2066" target="_blank"><img src="http://bermodashop.com/upload/ad_90.gif" /></a></div>'
);
```

`Math.floor(Math.random()*2)` is a random integrer between `0` and `1`.

But you should avoid using `document.write`.

And if http://goldenads.ir/showb.php?text=0&uid=230&c=2&mod=h&type=h and http://bermodashop.com/adcode/run/banner/h/horizontal/1/0/0/null//ref:2066 are JavaSCript files, you should serve them as `text/javascript`. Open the links in your browser and you will see what happens if you serve them as `text/html`.

**Edit:**

If the data contained in the scrips is variable, then you can use

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.type="text/javascript";
s.src=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)?"http://goldenads.ir/showb.php?text=0&uid=230&c=2&mod=h&type=h":"http://bermodashop.com/adcode/run/banner/h/horizontal/1/0/0/null//ref:2066";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

**Edit 2:**

It seems the code above doesn't work because `document.write` is buggy. Then, you can use another `document.write`:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)?"http://goldenads.ir/showb.php?text=0&uid=230&c=2&mod=h&type=h":"http://bermodashop.com/adcode/run/banner/h/horizontal/1/0/0/null//ref:2066")+'"><\/script>');
```

**Edit 3:**

If you want more than 2 scripts, you can use

```
var scripts=["http://goldenads.ir/showb.php?text=0&uid=230&c=2&mod=h&type=h",
    "http://bermodashop.com/adcode/run/banner/h/horizontal/1/0/0/null//ref:2066",
    "URL1",
    "URL2"];
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scripts[Math.floor(Math.random()*scripts.length)]+'"><\/script>');
```

Comment: thanks Oriol but my scripts Randomly show some pics and links from third party web site. white this codes they're not random any more. you can run my scripts in dreaweaver and compare theme

Comment: there is some error with this Line: s.src=Math.floor(Math.random()*2? [checked with dreamweaver]

Comment: @Amin Yes, I forgot `)`.

Comment: still doesn't show any thing in browser! have u checked it yourself?

Comment: I think it might be your 'Javascript' files. What are you trying to do ? When you link to a Javascript file and run it, (or use a function from it) you run code not get HTML. Sure you could make Javascript generate HTML but Javascript isn't HTML

Comment: @Amin Now it should work... But you shouldn't use `document.write`, it's very buggy and gives unexpected results.

Comment: Sorry Oriol, can u tell me how can i expand this script? i mean can i use this script for more than 2 scripts? how?